# redirect to profile page after registering

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am making a program in where a form will be submitted, then the user will be redirected to the profile page. If one of the items is blank, the form will restart. However, the comment section  & password of the registration is not displayed in the profile page, and that the registration does not restart when one of the items is left blank. Furthermore, the gender should also be included in display in the profile page, however, i have no idea how, since that it is a radio option.

Is there a typo in it? And how do I display the information that I haven't displayed? Thanks

Code (registration):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
        
</head>
<style type=text/css>
               ul {list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: rgb(42,157,143); overflow: hidden;}
                li{float: left;} 
                li a:link{display: block; color: black; padding: 10px; text-decoration: none;}
                li a:visited{color: orange;}
                li a:hover {background-color: rgb(38,70,83); color: blue;}
                li a.active {background-color: rgb(138,177,125); color: red;}
               .leftdiv
               {
               float: up;
               }
               .rightdiv
               {
               float: down;
               width: 100px;
               }
               div
               {
               padding : 1%;
               color: blue;
               background color: white;
               width: 40%;
               border: blue;
               }
               span
               {
               color : blue;
               background-color: white;
               margin: 8px;
               font-size: 25x;

               .sprite {
               display:block;
               position:relative;
               width:50px;
               height:50px;
               border:1px solid red;
               overflow:hidden;
               }
               #fb { 
               position:absolute;
               top:0;
               left:0;
               } 
               #fb:hover {
               position:absolute;
               top:-50px;
               left:0;
               }
        form
        {   
        
        color : blue;
               background-color: white;
               margin: 8px;
               font-size: 25x;
        }

            </style>
<body>
    <script>
        function passvalues()
        {
            var name=document.getElementById("name1").value;
            localStorage.setItem("textvalues", name);
            

            var name=document.getElementById("name2").value;
            localStorage.setItem("textvalue", name);
            

            var name=document.getElementById("email").value;
            localStorage.setItem("emailvalues", name);
            


            var name=document.getElementById("pword").value;
            localStorage.setItem("passwordvalues", name);
            


            var name=document.getElementById("tArea").value;
            localStorage.setItem("textareavalue", name);
            return false;
        }

    </script>
<body>
      <nav>  
          
        <form action="Profilepage.html">
            <fieldset form="signup" width=10px; style=border-style:solid; color : "black"; border-width:1px; padding:10px; text-align:left;">
                <legend>Register: </legend>

                <label for="name1">*First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name1" name="name1"  required/><br><br>
                <label for="name2">*Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name2" name="name2"  required/><br><br>

                <p>*Your Gender:</p>
                <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="Male"  required/>
                <label for="male">Male</label></br>
                <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="Female"  required/>
                <label for="female">Female</label></br>
                <input type="radio" id="prefernotsay" name="gender" value="Prefer not say"  required/>
                <label for="prefernotsay">Prefer Not Say</label>
                
                <br>
                <br>

                <label for="email">*Email Address:</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email"  required/><br><br>

                <label for="number">#Number:</label>
                <input type="text" id="number" name="Number"  required/><br><br>

                <label for="pword">*Your Password: </label>
                <input type="password" id="pword" name="pword" required/>
                
                <br>
                <br>

                <label for="cmmnts">*Reasons for registering: </label></br>
                <input type="textarea" textarea id="tArea" name="cmmnts" rows="4" cols="50" required/> </textarea>
                
                <br>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="passvalues()"/>

            </fieldset>
        </form>

     
      </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Code (Profilepage):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style type=text/css>
               ul {list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: rgb(42,157,143); overflow: hidden;}
                li{float: left;} 
                li a:link{display: block; color: black; padding: 10px; text-decoration: none;}
                li a:visited{color: orange;}
                li a:hover {background-color: rgb(38,70,83); color: blue;}
                li a.active {background-color: rgb(138,177,125); color: red;}
               .leftdiv
               {
               float: up;
               }
               .rightdiv
               {
               float: down;
               width: 100px;
               }
               div
               {
               padding : 1%;
               color: blue;
               background color: white;
               width: 40%;
               border: blue;
               }
               span
               {
               color : blue;
               background-color: white;
               margin: 8px;
               font-size: 25x;

               .sprite {
               display:block;
               position:relative;
               width:50px;
               height:50px;
               border:1px solid red;
               overflow:hidden;
               }
               #fb { 
               position:absolute;
               top:0;
               left:0;
               } 
               #fb:hover {
               position:absolute;
               top:-50px;
               left:0;
               }

            </style>
<body>
<div>
    <p>First Name: </p>
    <span id="name1"></span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>Last Name: </p>
    <span id="name2"></span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>Email: </p>
    <span id="email"></span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>Why I support this campaign: </p>
    <span id="tArea"></span>
</div>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("name1").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("textvalues");
    document.getElementById("name2").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("textvalue");
    document.getElementById("email").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("emailvalues");
    document.getElementById("pword").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("passwordvalues");
    document.getElementById("tArea").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("textArea");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pls read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). No one is going to sit and reads your whole code to debug it. You also need to give a title of the question which summarises the whole question is one line and **it should be in question format**.

Answer (score 1):

```
**home.html**

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

 <head>
        
  <style type=text/css>

   ul {list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: rgb(42,157,143); overflow: hidden;}
   li{float: left;} 
   li a:link{display: block; color: black; padding: 10px; text-decoration: none;}
   li a:visited{color: orange;}
   li a:hover {background-color: rgb(38,70,83); color: blue;}
   li a.active {background-color: rgb(138,177,125); color: red;}

   .leftdiv{
      float: up;
    }

    .rightdiv{
       float: down;
       width: 100px;
     }

     div{
       padding : 1%;
       color: blue;
       /* corrected  background color to background-color*/
       background-color: white; 
       width: 40%;
       border: blue;
     }
                    
     span{
        color : blue;
        background-color: white;
        margin: 8px;
        font-size: 25x;

         /* missing the close tag */
      }

      .sprite {
         display:block;
         position:relative;
         width:50px;
         height:50px;
         border:1px solid red;
         overflow:hidden;
       }

       #fb { 
         position:absolute;
         top:0;
         left:0;
            } 

            #fb:hover {
                position:absolute;
                top:-50px;
                left:0;
            }

            form{   
                
                color : blue;
                background-color: white;
                margin: 8px;
                font-size: 25x;
            }

        </style>

        <script>

            function passvalues()

                {
                    var name=document.getElementById("name1").value;
                    localStorage.setItem("textvalues", name);
                    

                    var name=document.getElementById("name2").value;
                    localStorage.setItem("textvalue", name);
                    
                    var radio= document.getElementById("myRadio").value
                    localStorage.setItem("emailvalues", name);

                    var name=document.getElementById("radio").value;
                    localStorage.setItem("emailvalues", name);


                    var name=document.getElementById("pword").value;
                    localStorage.setItem("passwordvalues", name);
                    


                    var name=document.getElementById("tArea").value;
                    localStorage.setItem("textareavalue", name);
                    return false;
                }

        </script>
            
    </head>

    <body>

        <nav>  
          
            <form action="profile.html">
                <!-- missed " in style" -->
                <fieldset form="signup" width=10px; style="border-style:solid; color : black; border-width:1px; padding:10px; text-align:left;"> 
                    <legend>Register: </legend>
    
                    <label for="name1">*First Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name1" name="name1"  required/><br><br>
                    <label for="name2">*Last Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name2" name="name2"  required/><br><br>
    
                    <p>*Your Gender:</p>
                    <input type="radio" id="radio" name="gender" value="Male"  required/>
                    <label for="male">Male</label></br>
                    <input type="radio" id="radio" name="gender" value="Female"  required/>
                    <label for="female">Female</label></br>
                    <input type="radio" id="radio" name="gender" value="Prefer not say"  required/>
                    <label for="prefernotsay">Prefer Not Say</label>
                    
                    <br>
                    <br>
    
                    <label for="email">*Email Address:</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email"  required/><br><br>
    
                    <label for="number">#Number:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="number" name="Number"  required/><br><br>
    
                    <label for="pword">*Your Password: </label>
                    <input type="password" id="pword" name="pword" required/>
                    
                    <br>
                    <br>
    
                    <label for="cmmnts">*Reasons for registering: </label></br>
                    <input type="textarea" textarea id="tArea" name="cmmnts" rows="4" cols="50" required/> </textarea>
                    
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="passvalues()"/>
    
                </fieldset>
            </form>
    
         
        </nav>

    </body>

</html>

**profile.hrml**

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

    <style type=text/css>
     
        ul {list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: rgb(42,157,143); overflow: hidden;}
        li{float: left;} 
        li a:link{display: block; color: black; padding: 10px; text-decoration: none;}
        li a:visited{color: orange;}
        li a:hover {background-color: rgb(38,70,83); color: blue;}
        li a.active {background-color: rgb(138,177,125); color: red;}

        .leftdiv{
            float: up;
        }

        .rightdiv{
            float: down;
            width: 100px;
        }

        div{
            padding : 1%;
            color: blue;
            background-color: white;
            width: 40%;
            border: blue;
        }

        span{
            color : blue;
            background-color: white;
            margin: 8px;
            font-size: 25x;
        }

        .sprite {
            display:block;
            position:relative;
            width:50px;
            height:50px;
            border:1px solid red;
            overflow:hidden;
                
        }

        #fb { 
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
        } 

        #fb:hover {
            position:absolute;
            top:-50px;
            left:0;
        }

    </style>

    <body>
        <div>
            <p>First Name: </p>
            <span id="name1"></span>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>Last Name: </p>
            <span id="name2"></span>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>Email: </p>
            <span id="email"></span>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>Why I support this campaign: </p>
            <span id="tArea"></span>
        </div>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("name1").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("textvalues");
            document.getElementById("name2").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("textvalue");
            document.getElementById("email").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("emailvalues");
            document.getElementById("pword").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("passwordvalues");
            document.getElementById("tArea").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("textArea");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

see what is the different between this code and your code I have set some comments there you have missed small parts in your code (you have done same mistakes in profile.html)

as well as dont use two body tag and you haven't close one body tag too

And if you want to get radio values you can simply use following code

```
   var radio= document.getElementById("myRadio").value
```

just make **id="myRadio"** use same ID for all the radio button then above code will get the clicked radio value

I have separate the code **home.html** and **profile.html**

You can test this creating two separate html file in same folder . Then copy and past the code to **home.html** and **profile.html** open the **home.html** in browser. after you input the value your page will be redirect to **profile.html** with the data that you input.

Answer (score 0):

You have two `<body>` in your Code (registration),and your  can put in the head like

```
<head>
  <script>
    xxx
  </script>
  <style>
    xxx
  </style>
</head>
```

make sure that your html tags in your body like

```
<body>
 <nav>
    xxx
 </nav>
</body>
```

and if you want get your radio select result,try

```
let gender = ''
document.getElementsByTagName("gender").forEach((item)=>{
if(item.checked){
 gender = item.value;
});
```